# how to cite 19th century newspaper articles from microfilms with BibTex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Assume that I am trying to create a BibTex citation for the notice in page 2, column 5 of the Detroit Gazette from December 11th, 1827, (available [here](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=scjTk0LcRdsC&dat=18271211&printsec=frontpage&hl=en)) which starts with the phrase "The Ohio Canal Fund commissioners ...."

As is typical of 19th century newspapers, the articles have neither author nor title (inferring that the editor wrote the article or making up a title is not going to fly with my history professors). Furthermore, I am using not the Google Newspaper version, but one from microfilm in reel 212 in the collection c.123 at XYZ University Library. I have dozens of newspaper notices that I need to cite, so some principled approach would be best.

Since the notice has neither author nor title, which are key fields for the majority of the bibtex styles, I am unsure which style to use or how to slot the information into the available styles.

I think my professors expect something like the following as output in the bibliography

> Detroit Gazette, 1817-1830. Microfilm edition. Detroit Gazette Collection, c.123, XYZ University Library, University Town, State.

and would be fine with something like this in the text (which ditches the reel number)

> ... as the Ohio Canal fund (Detroit Gazette, Dec 11 1827, p.2 c.5) ...

so that

```
\cite[Dec 11 1827, p.2 c.5]{dg-1817-1830-col}
```

seems like a nice way to refer to the entry.

Comment: Well, `@misc` is the catch-all entry type. Have you given it a try?

Comment: There is also the modern `biblatex` making it relatively easy to define a new entry type called `microfilmarticle` (or something else, you can make it up) and define fiels like `reel=212` and/or `collection=123`.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: `@misc` still requires `author` and `title`, I believe. I am using the `biblatex` style `authoryear` with `biber` as the back-end.

Comment: Is the proposal to use `@misc`, set `author` to `The Detroit Gazette`, the `title` to `1817-1830. Microfilm edition`, and the `note` to the rest of the collection information, i.e. `Detroit Gazette Collection, c.123, XYZ University Library, University Town, State`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the catch-all `@misc` entry type for this case, and use only two fields: `author` and `note`. (Most bibliography styles have no *required* fields for entries of type `@misc`; in particular, the `year` field isn't required for this entry type.) By placing double curly braces around "Detroit Gazette", you inform BibTeX that it's a "corporate author" rather than a person whose first and last names are "Detroit" and "Gazette", respectively. The precise content of the `note` field will have to conform to your institution's stylistic requirements.

If you use the `natbib` citation management package, you could use its `\citep` macro to create the citation call-out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc{dg,
  author = {{Detroit Gazette}},
  note   = {1817--1830. Microfilm edition, Detroit Gazette Collection, 
            c.~123, XYZ University Library, University Town, State},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a bibliography style that suits your needs

\begin{document}
\dots{} as the Ohio Canal fund \citep[Dec~11 1827, p.~2, c.~5]{dg} \dots
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```